# Can I modify bugs fields in BugZilla by reimporting XML?

Tags: bugzilla

In BugZilla, we can import data by reading XML files through [`importxml.pl`](http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/4.0/annotate/head:/importxml.pl).

Is it possible to update some fields of existing bugs by reading some XML file through `importxml.pl` or some other way? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Not via importxml.pl. However, email_in.pl can do this, but not in XML format.

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/api/email_in.html